# php multidimensional array json encode valid output

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

icant figure it out how to encode a valid json from my array
tried every posible way to encode json i had no luck
thankyou for your time

```
<?php
// this array is very large i used small piece as example
$listarray = array(
array(87,108,173,0,0),
array(87,108,173,0,1),
array(87,108,173,0,2),
array(87,108,173,0,3),
array(87,108,173,0,4),
array(87,108,173,0,5),
array(79,99,163,0,6),
array(79,99,163,0,7),
array(79,99,163,0,8),
array(79,99,163,0,9),
array(92,97,158,0,10),
array(92,97,158,0,11),
array(76,91,153,0,12),
array(79,99,163,0,13),
array(76,91,153,0,14),
array(92,97,158,0,15),
array(76,91,153,0,16),
array(76,91,153,0,17),
array(133,157,215,1,47),
array(133,157,215,1,48),
array(133,157,215,1,49),
array(133,157,215,1,50),
array(133,157,215,1,51),
array(133,157,215,1,52),
array(133,157,215,1,53),
array(143,168,222,1,54),
array(156,180,227,1,55),
array(156,180,227,1,56),
array(142,175,243,1,57),
array(156,180,227,1,58),
array(156,180,227,1,59),
array(156,180,227,1,60),
array(133,157,215,1,61));

for ($key = 0, $size = count($listarray); $key < $size; $key++) {
$array = array_values($listarray[$key]);
$line = $array[3]+1; //+1 start counting from 1
$loc = $array[4]+1; //+1 start counting from 1
$Name = $array[0].'_'.$array[1].'_'.$array[2];

$data = new StdClass();
$data->$line->$Name = array("$loc",);
$json = json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json."<br>";
//// echo give somthing like this and it is unusable for me
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "1" ] } }
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "2" ] } }
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "3" ] } }
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "4" ] } }
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "5" ] } }
//{ "1": { "87_108_173": [ "6" ] } }
////
$fh = fopen("jsonout.json", 'w')or die("Error opening output file");
fwrite($fh, json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
fclose($fh);
    }// end of for loop
?>
```

// and contents of jsonout.json is not valid
//the out put needed as shoud be exactly like this
// json blew is manualy made with app and validated

```
{
        "1": {
            "87_108_173": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
                "6"
            ],
            "92_97_158": [
                "11",
                "12",
                "16"
            ],
            "79_99_163": [
                "7",
                "8",
                "9",
                "14"
            ],
            "76_91_153": [
                "13",
                "15",
                "17",
                "18"
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            "156_180_227": [
                "56",
                "57",
                "59",
                "60",
                "61"
            ],
            "142_175_243": [
                "58"
            ],
            "133_157_215": [
                "48",
                "49",
                "50",
                "51",
                "52",
                "53",
                "54",
                "62"
            ],
            "143_168_222": [
                "55"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: googled for hours and looked every multidimensional related questions. i hade no luck

Comment: _googled for hours .... i hade no luck_ I don't agree. There are tons of tutorials ou there and you don't need to offer many hours to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$listarray = array(
  array(87,108,173,0,0),
  array(87,108,173,0,1),
  array(87,108,173,0,2),
  array(87,108,173,0,3),
  array(133,157,215,1,47),
array(133,157,215,1,48),
array(133,157,215,1,49),
array(133,157,215,1,50),
array(133,157,215,1,51),
array(133,157,215,1,52),
);

$resultArray = array();
foreach ($listarray as $row) {
  $ind = $row[3] + 1;
  $name = $row[0] . '_' . $row[1] . '_' . $row[2];
  $val = $row[4] + 1;

  if (!isset($resultArray[$ind])) {
    $resultArray[$ind] = array();
  }

  if (!isset($resultArray[$ind][$name])) {
    $resultArray[$ind][$name] = array();
  }

  $resultArray[$ind][$name][] = $val;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

You are welcome ;)